# mule code to add list in dataweave mule

Tags: json, merge, mule, mule-component, dataweave

I am trying to pull physical and mailing address from a JSON file. I am able to retrieve them separately but not able to merge them in the `dataweave`. The below dataweave code will provide physical address and mailing address list, but I want the one address list which contains both physical and mailing address.

Below is the dataweave code used:

```
    physicaladdress: payload01.attributes.PhysicalAddress map ((physicalAddress , indexOfPhysicalAddress) -> {
type: physicalAddress.value.AddressType.value ,
lineOne: physicalAddress.value.AddressLine1[0].value as :string ,
lineTwo: physicalAddress.value.AddressLine2[0].value as :string,
country: physicalAddress.value.Country[0].value as :string 
}) when payload01.attributes.PhysicalAddress != null  otherwise null,
    mailingaddress: payload01.attributes.MailingAddress map ((mailingAddress , indexOfMailingAddress) -> {
type: mailingAddress.value.AddressType.value ,
lineOne: mailingAddress.value.AddressLine1[0].value as :string,
lineTwo: mailingAddress.value.AddressLine2[0].value as :string ,
country: mailingAddress.value.Country[0].value as :string 
}) when payload01.attributes.MailingAddress != null otherwise null,
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Current response using the dataweave code attached:

```
    "physicaladdress": [
  {
    "type": "Physical",
    "addressLine1": "1166 Quail Ct310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  },
  {
    "type": "Physical",
    "addressLine1": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310-310 Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  }
],
"mailingaddress": [
  {
    "type": "Mailing",
    "lineOne": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310-310 Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  },
  {
    "type": "Mailing",
    "lineOne": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  }
]
```

Expected response:

```
    "address": [
  {
    "type": "Physical",
    "addressLine1": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  },
  {
    "type": "Physical",
    "addressLine1": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310-310 Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  },
{
    "type": "Mailing",
    "lineOne": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310-310 Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  },
  {
    "type": "Mailing",
    "lineOne": "1166 Quail Ct Ste 310",
    "cityName": "Pewaukee",
    "country": "United States"
  }
]
```

If i change the dataweave code to the one below, I will get only mailing address, think mailing address is overriding the physical address:

```
    address: payload01.attributes.PhysicalAddress map ((physicalAddress , indexOfPhysicalAddress) -> {
type: physicalAddress.value.AddressType.value ,
lineOne: physicalAddress.value.AddressLine1[0].value as :string ,
lineTwo: physicalAddress.value.AddressLine2[0].value as :string,
country: physicalAddress.value.Country[0].value as :string 
}) when payload01.attributes.PhysicalAddress != null  otherwise null,
    address: payload01.attributes.MailingAddress map ((mailingAddress , indexOfMailingAddress) -> {
type: mailingAddress.value.AddressType.value ,
lineOne: mailingAddress.value.AddressLine1[0].value as :string,
lineTwo: mailingAddress.value.AddressLine2[0].value as :string ,
country: mailingAddress.value.Country[0].value as :string 
}) when payload01.attributes.MailingAddress != null otherwise null,
```

I am looking for address having both the list (physical and mailing) example attached, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you :

```
Sample Input :

{

"physicaladdressList" : [
            "physicaladdress" : {
                "type":  "01" ,
                "lineOne": " 1st Address Line1(P)",
                "lineTwo": " 1st Address Line2 (P)",
                "country": "INDIA" 
             },
         "physicaladdress" :{
            "type":  "02" ,
            "lineOne": "2nd Address Line1(P)",
            "lineTwo": "2nd Address Line2(P)",
            "country": "INDIA" 
         },
          "physicaladdress" : {
            "type":  "03" ,
            "lineOne": "3rd Address Line1(P)",
            "lineTwo": "3rd Address Line2(P)",
            "country": "INDIA" 
         }
 ],
 "mailingaddressList" : [
          "mailingaddress" :{
                "type":  "04" ,
                "lineOne": "1st Address Line1(M)",
                "lineTwo": "1st Address Line2(M)",
                "country": "INDIA" 
             },
         "mailingaddress" : {
            "type":  "05" ,
            "lineOne": "2nd Address Line1(M)",
            "lineTwo": "2nd Address Line2(M)",
            "country": "INDIA" 
         },
         "mailingaddress" : {
            "type":  "06" ,
            "lineOne": "3rd Address Line1(M)",
            "lineTwo": "3rd Address Line2(M)",
            "country": "INDIA" 
         }]

 }

===============DataWeave===============================
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
%var phydata = payload.physicaladdressList.physicaladdress 
%var mailddata = payload.mailingaddressList.mailingaddress 
%var b = sizeOf (payload.physicaladdressList.physicaladdress)
%var a = 0
%var c= b - 1
---
   [[a][0] .. [c][0]] map {
        Address :
      {
          PhysicalAddress: 
            { 
                "Type" : phydata[$][0].type,
                "AddressLine1" : phydata[$][1].lineOne,
                "AddressLine2" : phydata[$][2].lineTwo,
                "Country" : phydata[$][3].country
            },
            MailingAddress: 
            { 
                "Type" : mailddata[$][0].type,
                "AddressLine1" : mailddata[$][1].lineOne,
                "AddressLine2" : mailddata[$][2].lineTwo,
                "Country" : mailddata[$][3].country
            }

       }             
          }

==========OutPut============================
[
  {
    "Address": {
      "PhysicalAddress": {
        "Type": "01",
        "AddressLine1": " 1st Address Line1(P)",
        "AddressLine2": " 1st Address Line2 (P)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      },
      "MailingAddress": {
        "Type": "04",
        "AddressLine1": "1st Address Line1(M)",
        "AddressLine2": "1st Address Line2(M)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Address": {
      "PhysicalAddress": {
        "Type": "02",
        "AddressLine1": "2nd Address Line1(P)",
        "AddressLine2": "2nd Address Line2(P)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      },
      "MailingAddress": {
        "Type": "05",
        "AddressLine1": "2nd Address Line1(M)",
        "AddressLine2": "2nd Address Line2(M)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Address": {
      "PhysicalAddress": {
        "Type": "03",
        "AddressLine1": "3rd Address Line1(P)",
        "AddressLine2": "3rd Address Line2(P)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      },
      "MailingAddress": {
        "Type": "06",
        "AddressLine1": "3rd Address Line1(M)",
        "AddressLine2": "3rd Address Line2(M)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Mowmita for you time. I have attached the current output and expected output to provide more info on the scenario which I am encountering.

Comment: @chethan : Use the following code :   %dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
%var mailddata = payload.mailingaddress 
---
 "Address" : payload.physicaladdress map {         
         "type" : $.type,
         "addressLine1" : $.addressLine1,
         "cityName" : $.cityName,
         "country" : $.country  
         } ++ mailddata

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
{
    "Address": {
      "PhysicalAddress": {
        "Type": "01",
        "AddressLine1": " PhysicalAddress Address Line1(P)",
        "AddressLine2": " PhysicalAddress Address Line2 (P)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      },
      "MailingAddress": {
        "Type": "04",
        "AddressLine1": "MailingAddress Address Line1(M)",
        "AddressLine2": "MailingAddress Address Line2(M)",
        "Country": "INDIA"
      }
    }
  }
```

### Dataweave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---


{Address : "MailingAddress": payload.Address.MailingAddress.AddressLine1
+"PhysicalAddress":payload.Address.PhysicalAddress.AddressLine1,
Address2 : "MailingAddress": payload.Address.MailingAddress.AddressLine2
+"PhysicalAddress":payload.Address.PhysicalAddress.AddressLine2}
```

### output

```
{"Address": {
"MailingAddress": [
  "MailingAddress Address Line1(M)",
  " PhysicalAddress Address Line1(P)"
]  "Address2": {
"MailingAddress": [
  "MailingAddress Address Line2(M)",
  " PhysicalAddress Address Line2 (P)"
]}}}
```

Comment: Thanks jitesh for you time. I should have provided the sample to explain the scenario. I have updated the query with the current output and expected output to provide more info on the scenario. Your help is greatly appreciated.